# Free Cloud Computing for VASP Simulation

Tags: vasp, software, high-performance-computing

I am looking for suggestions for a free cloud-computing platform for running the VASP simulations. I do have the VASP license. I am also ok, if I am allowed to use for a week or so.

I can also install the VASP there, in case it is not installed there.

Please do suggest something in this regard.

Regards

Comment: Have you tried to email the people at HPQC Labs? info@hpqc.org.